# How do I add Sylanders to my account?

Tags: skylanders

My brother has a Skylanders account and he wants to add another Skylander but we don't know how. I have been to the lair but it wont work. My dad added the first one for him but it just came up with a place to add a code when he made an account for my younger brother.

NOTE: This is on the website version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You click on the crown at the top. It will say "web code." Type your 10 letters and digits in.